# How to load HTML file when using the windows timeout function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to load my homepage HTML file after it a certain time frame. This is what I have right now:

```
 reply.file('./views/afteradd.html');
      setTimeout( function(){
        window.location.href= "views/add.html";
      }, 1000);
```

I want to load my add.html file after certain period however when I try to create a path to the my file I get an error. I have tried window.location and tried *.href. I'm pretty new in Java Script so it might be a really simple error im not finding. 
The error I'm getting is:
"Debug: internal, implementation, error

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined"
```

Comment: Please post your error

Comment: You need to redirect to another page after sometime or you need to create a link on that page which will go to another page?

Comment: "views/add.html" is not a valid URL.

Comment: @ndugger actually it is a relative path and it works pretty fine if there where something to show from the server

Comment: you might need to add a `/` in front of the `views/add.html`. Without it your new path will be added to the existing one.

Comment: @Burimi the problem is that setting the window location needs to be a full url; "views/add.html" is not a valid full URL, contianing the protocol, the host, etc. It's a relative path, yes, but not a valid URL.

Comment: @ndugger I don't see how that's a problem in that case. I understand it doesn't meet the requirements, but the engine will create something valid for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your add.html is not present in root location then please give full path in href

```
For this please try below code :

<script>
setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='http://yourdomainname/views/add.html'},1000);
</script>
```

And for home page add only '/'

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="/"},1000);
</script>
```

Comment: I tried using window.location.href = "/" but still getting the error saying         Debug: internal, implementation, error 

    ReferenceError: window is not defined,   and if I were to try with my domain name it wouldn't be very flexible to other domains cause right now I'm using gomix to create this.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try with this.

```
<script>
    var change_path = function(){window.location.href="/"};
    setTimeout(change_path ,1000);
</script>
```

Comment: i'm still getting this error:  Debug: internal, implementation, error 

    ReferenceError: window is not defined

    at Timeout.change_path [as _onTimeout] (/app/routes.js:44:36)

    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)

    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)

    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)